# IIS Not Displaying ASPX Pages

Tags: asp.net, iis

When running IIS, I'm getting the below error on all ASPX pages. ASP.NET is registered for versions 2.0 (with 3.5 extension) and 4.0. I'm running 2.0. Is there some setting I'm missing? I'm not sure what information is needed to better facilitate some help, so let me know what you need and I'll post it up as an edit.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

***ERROR MESSAGE***

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc.GetServerVariable(String name) +784
   System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +117
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: does the code run correctly in debug?    Normally i would say make sure that default.aspx (or whatever your launch page) is set in the documents list, but this seems more like a code issue.   is there a connection from your iis server to the database and are the db drivers installed?

Comment: This error indicates something is wrong with your code. We can't help you fix it unless we can see this code. If it happens on all pages, it may also be related to your web.config file.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's not a code related issue. It has to do with the framework or IIS I believe. The code is just some plain text "test".

Comment: @Brian I'm not using any sort of database. Does IIS inheritly use a DB? I noticed a setting for that, but it was set by default so I assume that's fine.

Comment: @steven - then check your web.config. The NulReference relates to trying to use a variable or property that is declared but with no object to back it up, and that means code of some kind.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn There is no web.config. I'm running a simple aspx page that has the text "test". It works fine as html and asp, but not as an aspx. There's no configuration that should be necessary. The same setup seems to work fine for a coworker of mine, but not in my environment, leading me to believe it's IIS or .NET framework that causes the issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a `NullReferenceException` is fairly easy to debug in code by debugging, but that stack trace appears to *begin* in framework code, so it's not *your* code that's failing.

In all likelihood, there's a problem with the .NET installation on IIS.  (The fact that it starts in `ISAPIWorkerRequestInProc` is the biggest clue, I think.  That's where the code interacts with the worker process.)  Try running:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

([info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx)) to re-install the IIS components of the framework.

Comment: I believe you're right about it being an IIS or Framework issue. I read over the information you linked to and the "-i" command seems linked to .NET4.0. I'm using 3.5. Will it re-install those components as well?

Comment: @steventnorris: `-i` should still be there in older versions.  Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  You might also use `-u` to first un-install, then `-i` to install.  It might just be a trial-and-error thing for a couple iterations.  One common cause of this issue is if IIS is installed after the .NET Framework.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was .NET specific exe. I thought it was an IIS specific exe. Apologies. I ran the -i for 2.0 and it worked like a charm. I did install IIS after the .NET framework, so that's probably the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly problem when I deployed my applications and took a while to find out that the reason was the asp.net version running on the application pool.

After I changed to 4.0 it started working

I hope that works for you too

Comment: The app pool doesn't specify the ASP.NET version, it specifies the CLR version.

Comment: I can't change to 4.0 unfortunately. The production environment is running 3.5, so my I have to run 3.5 to ensure everythings fine when we push over the changes (I'm running IIS as a local test environment)

Comment: I can't think of anything that can break by converting from 3.5 to 4.0 - bite the bullet, at least in your dev env?

Comment: I'd like to mirror the test completely, just to err on the side of safety, but the answer David provided worked like a charm.